# Transferring values between sheets using Vlookup on excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have 2 excel sheets that I am trying to vlook up to transfer values.

The first sheet Attendance is a csv file generated by python that records facial ID's and the time they were scanned.
[image: Attendance csv]

The second sheet is book1 which will contain a list of all students in the school. I want to look for the ID's that match and transfer the time entered value.

[image: Sheet1]

This is the formula I am using   **=VLOOKUP(A2,Attendance!$A$1:$C$29,2,FALSE)**

I can get he vlookup to find a match but cannot get it to transfer the value of Time entered. Hoping someone can help as I am an excel noob.

Comment: You formula looks fine. I think you have white space before of after student id in attendance sheet or sheet1. Check your data. You can also use `INDEX/MATCH` instead of `VLookup()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to force all to string:

***E2***

```
=VLOOKUP(TRIM(A2&""),TRIM(Attendance!$A$1:$C$29&""),2,0)
```

on older version confirm as array formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Bye